# Why can I use NumPy with Python 3.8 which was preinstalled but not with Python 3.9 which I installed in addition?

Tags: python, ubuntu-20.04

I installed Ubuntu 20.04, and python3 (3.8) is installed by default.
To install python3.9, I executed:

```
sudo apt install python3.9
```

Thus, I have two versions of Python at my laptop: 3.8 and 3.9.

I'm trying to launch the simple script:

```
import numpy
```

With Python 3.8 it works correctly. But, when I interp my script by Python 3.9 the error occurs:

[image]

How to solve this problem?

I've already tried to update numpy using pip, nothing has happened.

```
pip3 install numpy --upgrade
```

Comment: `python3.9 -m pip install numpy`

Comment: pip is tied to an interpreter, so you installed numpy for one but not the other

Comment: I've tried, but it seems that python3.9 already fitted by numpy: "Requirement already satisfied: numpy in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (1.17.4)"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Likely what is happening here is, because you have 2 versions of python installed, your `pip3` command is only installing things for one of the versions, 3.8 in this case.

Specifying the python version you want to run your command with will help solve this issue.

For example,

```
python3.9 -m pip install numpy
```

or

```
python3.8 -m pip install numpy
```

Comment: Thank you for advice, but trying the both commands, I've got a message:
"Requirement already satisfied: numpy in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (1.17.4)"

Comment: Have you attempted to uninstall numpy using python3.9 and reinstalling?

Comment: Yes, I've uninstall numpy using apt remove and pip, afterwhich I installed it again using python3.9. Now it works! Thank you for help!

Answer (score 1):

You can install a package for a specific version of Python with

```
python3.9 -m pip install numpy
```

For a more consistent python environment look at python [venv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html) or a container.

Comment: I afraid it won't help: "Requirement already satisfied: numpy in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (1.17.4)"